# Haskell: Function receiving a null list

Tags: list, haskell, max

here are some type definitions in my program FYI:

```
type BitString -> String

type Plateau -> [BitString]
```

I have a function called:

```
--Extract will take a list of lists, and return the inner list of the most items. Empty list should return ["00000"]


extract::[Plateau]->Plateau
extract _ = ["00000"]
extract (x:xs)
  |x==maximumBy(compare `on` length)xs=x  --thanks SOF
  |otherwise = extract (xs)
```

The problem is, no matter what i do, extract returns `["00000"]`

here are some outputs from GHCI, that are working:

```
>plateau graycodes
[["01000"],["01010","11010","10010"],["00101"],["01101","01001"]]
```

this is expected, and is in the form of a `[Plateau]` since this is a list of lists of string.

```
>maximumBy(compare `on` length)(plateau graycodes)
["01010","11010","10010"]

>extract (plateau graycodes)
["00000"]
```

in this case, i know for sure that extract will be called with a not empty `[Plateau]`.  But the `_` part of the function is returning.

I have tried also:

```
extract (x:xs)
  |x==[]=["00000"]
  |x==[""]=["00000"]
  |x==maximumBy(compare `on` length)xs=x  --thanks SOF
  |otherwise = extract (xs)


error: List.maximumBy: Empty list
```

Comment: Haskell tries the expressions in order. Since _ catches anything, it'll always use that definition. Try to swap the two definitions (put the _ one last).

Comment: Your second attempt fails because you're trying to match `[]` to `(x:xs)`. Those don't match --- there's no `:` in `[]` --- and so it never gets to your guards. We don't check whether `x == []` because `[]` can never match `(x:xs)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting that error, because you are not passing in your list `(x:xs)` to maximumBy:

```
extract :: [Plateau] -> Plateau
extract (x:xs)
    |x == maximumBy (compare `on` length) (x:xs) = x
    |otherwise = extract (xs)
extract _ = ["00000"]
```

or, preferably,

```
extract :: [Plateau] -> Plateau
extract s@(x:xs)
    |x == maximumBy (compare `on` length) s = x
    |otherwise = extract (xs)
extract _ = ["00000"]
```

(this also adds a needed `=` after your `otherwise`)

**EDIT:**

I was not satisfied with my answer, or your acceptance of that answer.

I believe this is the code you are really after:

```
extract :: [Plateau] -> Plateau
extract (x:[]) = x
extract s@(x:xs) = maximumBy (compare `on` length) s
extract _ = ["00000"]
```

Comment: Corrent, that is because i dont want it to have all of the x:xs.  Then it will go on for ever.  If the first x is not the max, then i want to send the tail of the list and check again.

Comment: I guess what I mean is, `maximumBy (compare 'on' length)` is partially applied.  It isn't a value - it's a one-parameter function.  Now that I think about it, this whole operation is redundant, excepting your fall-through case of `["00000"]`

Comment: Sorry, that was a type-o on my part.  The function does use xs

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  And i corrected my Issue.  Thank you.  I needed to send the maximumBy()(x:xs) and not just (xs).  Not sure exactly why.  but it works.

Comment: there are a few things i dont understand in your edit.  But that is something i shall research on my own.  Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Please, ask away, I'm happy to help you.

Answer (score 4):

When you define a function with multiple patterns, they will be tried in order from top to bottom. The problem is that your topmost pattern of `extract` will match *anything*, and therefore the first case will always be chosen.

The solution is to either reorder them, or change the first pattern to only match the empty list:

```
extract []     = ["00000"]
extract (x:xs) = ...
```

Comment: didnt i do this, in the second part.  But my maximumBy still errors on an "empty list".

Comment: It looks like you didn't copy the code correctly into your question. Which list are you using `maximumBy` on? `xs`?

Comment: @Special--k: No, you didn't. Pattern matching and testing for equality are *not the same.*

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, switch place of the cases of extract. The pattern `extract _` will always match,
thus the second case will never be executed.

Working code (hopefully):

```
--Extract will take a list of lists, and return the inner list of the most items. Empty list should return ["00000"]

extract::[Plateau]->Plateau
extract (x:xs)
  |x==maximumBy(compare `on` length)=x  --thanks SOF
  |otherwise extract (xs)
extract _ = ["00000"]
```